# Fetch Metadata SPL Token 2022

Tags: solana-program, token-2022, spl

How can I fetch the metadata of an SPL Token in 2022?

I attempted to fetch it from UMI, but it failed. It works fine with SPL 2020, but it's showing an error

```
    const umi = createUmi("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com").use(
    mplTokenMetadata());
    
     const mintAddress = umiPublicKey(
      "7usVzynPTUJ9czdS96ezm9C6Z3hCsjb7j6TMKipURyyQ"
    );

    const asset = await fetchDigitalAsset(umi, mintAddress);
    console.log("asset", asset);
```

**Error:**

Error fetching owner Info: AccountNotFoundError: The account of type [Metadata] was not found at the provided address [ESo96eKA5QsXAVUrHUR66qnbVMNy83v16Mut9RFBrh7X].

Source: SDK

**EDIT**

Token That I'm searching
https://solscan.io/token/7usVzynPTUJ9czdS96ezm9C6Z3hCsjb7j6TMKipURyyQ

Answer (score 1):

The method is the same for SPL and Token2022 tokens.

It looks like the token you're searching for doesn't exist yet.

**Edit:**

You need to use UMI publickeys for UMI instructions.

```
import { publicKey as umiPublicKey } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi";

const mintAddress = umiPublicKey("token address here"));
```

**Edit 2:**

It might be the case that this token isn't using the metaplex metadata program and is using the experimental token2022 metadata program that some token creators were using a while ago.

I'm not entirely sure if you can fetch the metadata for those through UMI sorry.

Comment: thanks for reply, check I edit the question with token address

Comment: Ah okay, edited my answer now

Comment: Doing the same, and got the same error...edited my answer now.

Comment: So this is working with other tokens but not this one?

Comment: On standard 2020 it works fine, but 2022 makes issues.